# Memorize large strings in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome extension that will store potentially large code snippets (with the snippet's name) from the user and use them.

I want the user to be able to upload files containing these snippets (or, even better, to copy and paste these snippets into a `textarea` in the extension's options page).

And, the tricky part, I want these snippets to be memorized by the extension in order to be accessible the next time user starts Chrome.

What kind of storage do you think I should use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is average size of code snippet?

Depend on answer you can use:

1) localStorage - easiest solution but have size limitations. 5Mb based on data from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

2) chromeStorage - with "unlimitedStorage" permission can store more data, can be synced between devices with storage.sync. See more on: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: I can't really tell about the average size because the user should be able to use their own scripts. I guess 5 Mb of code per user should be fine.

Comment: Regarding `chromeStorage`, I've seen it's limited to 5 MB when using `storage.local` and 100 kB when using `storage.sync`. Although it would be cool to sync users's data on their Google account. Does the "unlimitedStorage" applies to `storage.sync` too ?

Comment: @SeevenByakko Unlimited storage would only apply to `storage.local`.

Comment: Are data stored with `storage.local` affected by softwares like CCleaner when cleaning "cookies & browser data" ?

Comment: @SeevenByakko I doubt it. It would not be affected by Chrome's built-in browsing data clean, and if CCleaner wipes all Chrome storage data - it would wipe settings for lots of apps/extensions. _That said, I've heard horror stories of CCleaner horribly maiming machines, so YMMV_

Comment: @Xan: Is it possible to use `storage.local` and `storage.sync` in the same extension ? So I could propose the users to sync their favorite snippets and inform them of their remaining syncing capacity.

Comment: Yes, you can. If you have further questions, this is not the appropriate place to ask; formulate a new question and ask away.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise cloud back-end, just because it's cool:) have a look at one of those:

1. https://parse.com - quite powerful one with lots of features
2. https://www.firebase.com - less  features but still very popular

Until certain limits the usage of both services is free.

### Update

Parse.com [pricing page](https://parse.com/plans) even says you can have up to 20GB of database for free. Their [FAQ](https://www.parse.com/plans/faq) reads:

> **What happens when I exceed 20GB of database storage?**
>
> The overage rate for database size is $10/GB but we only allow increases in increments of 20GB. When you you exceed 20GB of database size we will increase your soft limit to 40GB and begin charging you an incremental $200/month.

Comment: So if I subscribe to a free Parse account, my total application's storage capacity will be 20 GB ? So the total amount of all the users's data must be of 20 GB max, is that correct ?

Comment: @SeevenByakko I believe, yes. This is what the web site says `When you you exceed 20GB of database size we will increase your soft limit to 40GB and begin charging you an incremental $200/month.`

Comment: I think I'll stick with `chrome.storage` for now, but I keep these cloud back-end solutions in mind for further projects (or further improvements of this one).